# Pretty URL for .html with parameters

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I have a website which consists only from `.html` frontend and I want to have pretty URLs. My goal is to create something like this

```
http://test.com/mypage.html  => http://test.com/mypage
http://test.com/mypage1.html => http://test.com/mypage1
```

and for one specific page

```
http://test.com/my-prettlink.html?id=1 => http://test.com/my-prettlink/1
```

I tried this `.htaccess` which is located in project root but only removing `.html` works.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [L]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^my-prettylink/(\d+)*$ ./my-prettylink.html?id=$1
```

Comment: The last rewrite route will never be reached. It has to come first, since it is more specialized. The more general rules come more towards the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More specific rules should come before general rules. So, try:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /subdirectory/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /(subdirectory/my-prettylink)\.html\?id=(\d+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^my-prettylink\.html$ /%1/%2? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /(subdirectory/.+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^my-prettylink/(\d+)$ my-prettylink.html?id=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(?!js|css) %{REQUEST_URI}.html [L]
```

and also add `<base href='/subdirectory/' />` in header

Comment: When I hit `my-prettylink?id=1` link is not changed (but page works) and also `my-prettylink/1` throws me `not found`. When I remove slash in front of `/my-prettylink.html?id=$1 [L]` also not found

Comment: @JozefDúc Where are the files located? Where are you putting the rewrite rules? Do you want the ugly URLs to be redirected to pretty ones as well?

Comment: files are located in same directory as `.htaccess` file. I want to redirect only one page with query string to pretty URL (as I wrote in question) and also from all URLs remove `.html` extension

Comment: @JozefDúc All files are in the server root directory? Or in some subdirectory. I'll update the reply accordingly.

Comment: whole page is located in subdirectory

Comment: @JozefDúc Updated the rules. Not that `subdirectory` needs to be replaced with the actual name of subdirectory where files are.

Comment: You really rock! Now when I hit `pretty-url/1` works fine, but my assest located in `subdirectory/css` or `subdirectory/js` etc are getting 500 internal error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95264/discussion-between-hjpotter92-and-jozef-duc).